# Managing new lines in Base64

Tags: java, base64

I am working on a java project that send an XML files to another application that send mails to many users.

In my XML, I want to set the content in attachment so I use Base64.

My problem is that the content of my mails is on multiple lines, but i don't know how to use Base64 so the users can get the content of attachments  with new lines.

What user must receive in the attachment:

```
20181231 IT FR 00188660 00188770
20181231 IT FC 00000914 00000921
20181231 DE FR 00424997 00425093
20181231 DE FC 00000558 00000567
```

what they get:

```
20181231 IT FR 00188660 0018877020181231 IT FC 00000914 0000092120181231 DE FR 00424997 0042509320181231 DE FC 00000558 00000567
```

So my question is how to set new lines in attachment with base64?

My JAVA code:

```
line = in.readLine();
byte[] bytesEncoded = Base64.encodeBase64(line.substring(22).getBytes());
fstream.write(bytesEncoded);
```

I read a line from a flat file and i encode it in base64 and i write the result in an XML file

Comment: Please **[edit]** your questions and add the Java code that produces the XML and the actual XML it generates.

Comment: Base 64 can encode newlines, so there must be another bug in your program.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name done

Comment: That code doesn't generate an XML file.

Comment: i write in a xml file that i open before this lines

Comment: FileOutputStream fstream = new FileOutputStream(chemin+"/"+prefixe+objets[k]+num_mail[k]+".xml", true);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base64 encodes new line character just like any other character. You can confirm it by encoding a simple two-line text:

```
String input = "a\nb";
String encoded = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(input.getBytes());
String output = new String(Base64.getDecoder().decode(encoded));
System.out.println(output);
```

will encode `a\nb` as `YQpi` and output:

```
a
b
```

Comment: I will contact the responsable of the other application because that is exactly what i did in my code. May be it's the other app that delete my new lines.

Comment: Thank you :) :) :)

Comment: @sfox part of XML processing is [normalization](https://www.w3.org/2008/xmlsec/Drafts/xml-norm/Overview.html). This step can remove new lines if they are not encoded correctly.